# Analysis On Manifolds: Munkres, James R, confusion about Lemma 25,2

Tags: analysis

[image]

By the theorem 16.3 in this book, I know that $A$ as a union of open sets $A_V$, there exists a partition of unity on it. I denote it as $\{\phi_i\}$. Then for each $x\in A$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of it so that there's only finitely many support of $\phi$ intersects with $U$. This is the local finiteness. But I don't get why this guarantees there are only finitely many $\phi$ that are not identically zero on $M$ Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: You refer to a book, and even copied a piece of it, and never mention the title or the author. Don't do that!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez "Analysis on Manifolds" (Munkres) is indeed the title, though I agree the author should be mentioned as well for clarity.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez Yes you are right. I already added the name of the author.

Comment: Remember that $M$ is compact, and therefore it is possible to restrict the sets $A_V$ to a finite collection.